# SSRS - How to repeat Table Header on every page with different data?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

In an SSRS report, instead of a page header, I've a table header that I've made to repeat at the top of every page. I can't use page header since it is a sub-report and headers/footers of a sub-reports get over-ridden by the main report.

The report prints labor hours for all employees, with each employees record appearing on a new page. The table header repeats correctly on top of every page. When I run the report, it prints out labor hour for all employees. What I want is to display respective employee's name in this table header, however, the report is repeating the first employee name on the top of every page. How can I fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Whats the Expression for that field?

Comment: =ReportItems!Name.Value should give you correct result assuming the report is grouped correctly.

Comment: @Filburt the value of the expression is `="Name: " + Fields!Name.Value`

Comment: @AlanSchofield I'm using the `Fields!Name.Value`, however, the issue is that the value doesn't get re-evaluated at the top of each page. My guess is that it gets evaluated only at the beginning of the first page, and on following pages, it just gets replicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the the reportitems value as suggested but only in your header expression, that should work

Comment: I'm getting a grouping error **Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope**